# Gaps or bleeding between tiles when using Tiled2Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I am seeing gaps or bleeding between my tiles when exporting from Tiled2Unity into Unity itself. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because your game tab's aspect ratio has a fractional number of pixels for width or height. Click on the resolution in the top of the Game tab (it probably says Free Aspect or 4:3 or something) and click on the plus on the bottom to add a new aspect ratio.

Type an exact number of pixels for width and height and you will force the aspect ratio to always have a whole number of pixels. The bleeding will go away.